# dependent "time change" of a.s. convergent random variables

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of random variables, s.t. $\frac{X_n}{n^p}\to X$ a.s. for some $p>0$. Now let $(Y_t)$ be a discrete stochastic process, s.t. $\frac{(Y_t)^p}{t}\to Y>0$ a.s. We only know that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, but we don't have independence of the terms $X_n$ and $Y_t$!

Now, does one have $\frac{X_{Y_t}}{t}\to XY$ a.s. or in probability?

Ideas: Let $\omega\in\Omega\setminus\mathcal{N}$ (where $\mathbb{P}[\mathcal{N}]=0$) be s.t. $\frac{X_n(\omega)}{n^p}\to X(\omega)$ and $\frac{(Y_t(\omega))^p}{t}\to Y(\omega)>0$. Then since $Y(\omega)>0$, the sequence $(Y_t(\omega))^p\to\infty$. 
Thus $\frac{X_{Y_t(\omega)}}{(Y_t(\omega))^p}\to X(\omega)$, since this is just a subsequence.

But $\frac{(Y_t(\omega))^p}{t}\to Y(\omega)$. Thus $\frac{X_{Y_t(\omega)}}{t}=\frac{X_{Y_t(\omega)}}{(Y_t(\omega))^p}\frac{(Y_t(\omega))^p}{t}\to X(\omega)Y(\omega)$.
I'm afraid my argument goes wrong somewhere, since I don't need indepencence of $X$ and $Y$ and I'm rather sure, that the result shouldn't hold in general....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi it appears to me that you have done the hardest part. To finish the job you only have to apply of the [Continuous Mapping Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem).

So you have already proven that $(W_t,Z_t)\to (X,Y)$ almost surely where $W_t =\frac{X_{Y_t}}{Y_t^p}$ and $Z_t=\frac{Y_t^p}{t}$

Now take $g(w,z)=w.z$ and apply Continuous Mapping Theorem to obtain almost sure convergence of $\frac{X_{Y_t}}{(Y_t)^p}\frac{(Y_t)^p}{t}=W_t.Z_t=g(W_t,Z_t)$ to $g(X.Y)=X.Y$

Best regards

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So after all, no independence is needed? I read the lines, I get the (idea of the) proof, still I wonder a little about the result. Before I accept your answer, let me digest the problem a little more, thx again!

Comment: @Mr Barrington : You might add an a.s. hypothesis about the strict positivity of $Y_t$. And yes independence has nothing to do with the convergence result, by the way you might notice you said that you knew that X and Y were independent but if you didn't knew that or worse if it were false from the beginning, it wouldn't have change anything in the line of argumentation and the result would still hold. Best regards

Comment: I'm feeling (rather) confident with the solution now, thank's again for your support and your input!